# Using web-server to substitute for GUI in python

Tags: python, user-interface

I have a GUI project which I am about to start. GUI requirement is simple ( though not as simple as tkinter will suffice). So I need to use a GUI toolkit for python (which will be wxpython if I have to go for GUI). Now I am thinking, why cannot I use simple web-framework such as cherrypy or bottlepy (sorry, if I am not thinking right. I am newbie to server-side programming) and create html pages as my graphical interface and use DOM ( again,I guess, I am speaking right) rather than using wxpython to create the overall GUI. I can then, write all of my business logic and leave the rest to simple html rendering where I have to spend less time in formatting tables, creating buttons and forms and worrying about the sizers.

My question is: Can somebody use web-server python package such as cherrypy or similar and get-away from using graphical toolkit? Is it really beneficial or am I thinking this thing upside down?

The benefit I am expecting:

I can use jquery to have many features which might take lot of time to create with wxpython or other GUI toolkit. For example, if I want to have autocomplete feature as similar to jquery, it is whole lot of different story in GUI toolkit like wxpython. And also, lot of drag and drop features are easy in html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes -- this is then just a web application instead of a native application.

Advantages include portability (assuming you can run the python code on any setup -- not sure what your application's purpose is) and not dealing with pesky layout issues and TK events and such.

However, you are also dramatically changing the paradigm in which you are programming. Depending on your goals, this may not matter.

As for using a web-framework:

In the simplest case, you could run a set of python scripts under CGI. Or you could get an MVC framework with a database abstraction layer (DAL/ORM) like django or web2py.

If you want to get up and running quickly I would suggest web2py -- simple to install and comes with a built-in server so you don't need to set up an apache instance and mess with Proxying or mod_wsgi or all that goodness.

You should DEFINITELY go to w3c ( http://www.w3schools.com/ ) and brush up on CSS/HTML if you haven't marked up a webpage in a while.

But yes -- web2py will allow you to run any python modules/packages, though you will have to learn to deal with the client-server model and realize that clientside events must be handled in javascript, whereas python code can only be executed on the server and then only from a request URI.

In short, there will be some 'glue' code, but that's what web2py (IMHO) excels at.

http://web2py.com
https://www.djangoproject.com/
http://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, but [don't roll your own](http://pyjs.org/).

Comment: Pardon me but I am even not thinking about installing apache. I don't know if I am wrong but do I need to have apache for web2py or django? I am not even thinking of installing apache. Just a simple-web-server, embedded!

Comment: There are several standalone WSGI containers.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades with web2py you do NOT need apache. You DO need a webserver of some sort for an HTML-based GUI app. Web2py comes with a standalone light webserver called "rocket". You don't need to mess with apache at all, but you DO need to make sure the server is started to interpret requests and send them to the framework. Not sure about django. Also, you could use lighttpd ( http://www.lighttpd.net/ ), but you probably need a webserver... unless you just linked files with the "file:" protocol... then it might work actually, but you could run into problems depending on your apps purpose

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Django has its own built-in server, but is fully wsgi compatible.

Comment: Don't use Django's built-in web server. No, don't argue, you're wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You think absolutely right. There are loads of python-based frameworks, just choose the right one: pyramid, pylons, django are the most popular and widely-used.

I suggest you to outsource HTML/CSS slicing to some professional instead of doing it by yourself. You can face up quite a lot of browser-specific things, which will waste your time, but obvious for an experienced person.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades +1 for note on outsourcing HTML/CSS -- if you don't have experience developing html pages, then wxpython might be an easier way to layout your application. If you're developing this app and its not open to the larger internet, you could specify WHICH browser is required to use, but generally web developers cannot do that. Again, it depends on nature of the application (audience/user-base, are you serving this from a server or localhost, meaning multiple installations which is not usually how web dev is done)

Answer (score 1):

No, you are thinking of this correctly.  HTML/CSS is very simple it can lend to rapid development.  Additionally python micro frameworks will make creating your business logic a breeze.  This is a very straight forward sipmle route to take.